# How to delete table in navicat c#

Tags: c#, sql, navicat

im try to make this table empty every 12 hour

my code:

```
#region Vote System
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 12 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 00 && DateTime.Now.Second == 00)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(MySqlCommandType.DELETE).Delete("votes", "delete", "1");
                cmd.Execute();

            }

            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 23 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 59 && DateTime.Now.Second == 40)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(MySqlCommandType.DELETE).Delete("votes", "delete", "1");
                cmd.Execute();
            }

            #endregion
```

No errors in my console, i don't know why this code is not working

Comment: Those are really specific times. Is your code running at those times? Does *this specific piece* of code happens to run at that time, and not some other part of the program?

Comment: Yes this code working in this time but its not working i don't know why..

Comment: So you are certain that the program goes into the if statement?

Comment: You might want to use something like Hangfire for this: http://hangfire.io/

Comment: Yes @Arperum , this code is not wrong right?

Comment: @Oluwafemi no i can't understand what you are talking about, can you give me full code?

Comment: Click the link on my comment above. You will find documentation there.